# Some conflicting dependencies were found. The following dependency versions were modified:

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, admob, facebook-audience-network

Hello i am using unity 2018.4 and i have implemented Admob and Audience Network ads i am using this for a year there were no issues. but now when i resolve the dependencies i am getting a warring

```
Some conflicting dependencies were found.
The following dependency versions were modified:
com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+ --> com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:+
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a proper answer but it might help you in overcoming the current issue.
Recently, FAN has added a new dependency at 6.0.0 which result in changing of adsetting values. you need to change some scripts.
But while resolving is complete you can place old arr file of facebook audience network, this way it can help you remove the error

Comment: We still waiting FAN would get update for unity at 6.0.0 so that this issue get resolved

Comment: Hello thank you very much for your response. i turned off auto resolution and onbuild resolution and place old resolved libraries in plugin android and its working.

Comment: How to do that?